# RequireJS - How do I conditionally expose functions of a module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a module, which among other things has two read functions. One uses FileReader, the other uses XHR to read a file. Different modules of a single page app use this module.

I want to be able to run the app to just use one or the other. Is there a way to do this via require.config in the data-main js file? Ideally a flag set via a url pararmeter (such as ?mode=file|xhr) can be used for this setup.

See below for current module code, where both functions are exposed. Other modules use it but the developers have to manually switch between the two functions. Instead *when the module loads* for the first time, I would like to expose just one read function, which all other modules use without knowing what is used under the hood. The condition of what to expose would come from app settings or a url param.

```
define(['somedep'], function(somedep) {
     function fileReader(){...};
     function xhrReader(){...};
     return { 
          fr: fileReader, xr: xhrReader
     }
}
```

Comment: What determines which read function to use? Can you post some code so we can get a better picture of your issue?

Comment: @ItoPizarro I have updated the question. Hope it is clear.

Comment: How are the modules using the code you managing to "manually switch between the two functions"? Are they not checking some condition by which they decide to run one function or the other? What prevents from moving that logic into your reading module?

Comment: @Louis right now nothing sophisticated. Just being commented in and out by a dev. So I am basically looking for a pattern to get rid of that.

Comment: I see. I've edited to clarify the language a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right — and I should say it is highly dependent on what you mean by "app parameters" you can do your condition-checking right in the module.

```
define(['somedep'], function(somedep) {

    function isXHR(){
        // do your testing logic (parese the URL | look for the app parameters) such that you can return a boolean
        return boolean_test_result;
    };

    function fileReader(){...};
    function xhrReader(){...};

    if ( isXHR() ){
        return {
            new_consolidated_method_name: xhrReader
        };
    } else {
        return { 
            new_consolidated_method_name: fileReader
        }
    }
}
```

The `isXHR` function could, as easily, be `isFile`; the point being that this is a binary decision that can be expressed as and interpreted as a `boolean`. Whicheever condition is `true`, allows you to infer the obverse if it is `false`. Introducing the `new_consolidated_method_name` means you would have to refactor the modules/methods that depended on using `fr` or `xr` but you would save yourself having to test which to use in all those instances, too.

Comment: Hey thanks. This is kind of what I did. The missing bit is the way to pass in the isXHR value, when the module loads using module.config().isXHR. Require allows that to be set in a "config" key like so require.config({baseUrl:'something'}, {'config': {'readermodule':getURLParams['useXHR']})

Comment: It works but am not sure if this is the right pattern.